# Parsing HTML text for Adobe InDesign--tags inside other tags

Tags: javascript, xml, adobe-indesign

In InDesign, I'm pulling text out of an xml file and placing it in a textFrame. Since the textFrame doesn't support some tags, I have to replace bold, italic and boldItalic tags in the textFrame with formatting applied programatically. I was originally doing this using Adobe's GREP search/replace, but if a tag was inside another tag it didn't work right (e.g., '`<b>a<i>b</i>c</b>`').  So I decided to use brute force and split the string by the tags and then loop through each item. The code I came up with works, but I'm curious if there's a better, more efficient way to do this?

Currently, it stores the font, and the text position to add that font to. The tags are also removed.

Note: There is a separate font that styles the text both bold and italic.  My apologies if I caused any confusion with the `<bi>` tag.  It was meant to be a tag for a character that needs to be both bold and italic.  `<b><i>text</i></b>` may be a better solution.  In any case, it is definitely needed as a separate style for appropriate characters.

```
var TAGSOBJ = {'<b>': 'Arial\tBold',
               '<i>': 'Arial\tItalic',
               '<bi>': 'Arial\tBold Italic',
               '</b>': 'Arial\tBold',
               '</i>': 'Arial\tItalic',
               '</bi>': 'Arial\tBold Italic'};
var BGNTAGSOBJ = {'<b>': null, '<i>': null, '<bi>': null};
var ENDTAGSOBJ = {'</b>': null, '</i>': null, '</bi>': null};

var txt = 'This is some <b>really important <i>text</i></b> with <i>some <b>very <bi>very <br> very</bi> important</b> things</i> in it.';

var n = 0;
var prevTag = '';
var noTagTxt = '';
var dataArray = [['none']];

var txtArray = txt.split(/(<\/?(?:b|i|bi)>)/);

for (var i = 0; i < txtArray.length; i++) {
    var iTxt = txtArray[i];

    if (iTxt in BGNTAGSOBJ) {
        dataArray.push([TAGSOBJ[iTxt]]);
        prevTag = iTxt;
    } else if (iTxt in ENDTAGSOBJ) {
        if (prevTag in ENDTAGSOBJ) {
            dataArray[dataArray.length - 1][0] = TAGSOBJ[iTxt];
        }

        dataArray.push(['none']);
        prevTag = iTxt;
    } else if (iTxt.length > 0) {
        var iTxtLen = iTxt.length;

        dataArray[dataArray.length - 1].push([n, n + (iTxtLen - 1)]);

        noTagTxt += iTxt;

        n += iTxtLen;
    } else {
        dataArray[dataArray.length - 1][0] = 'none';
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
    $.writeln(dataArray[i]);  // print to console in extendscript
}
$.writeln(noTagTxt);

/* Outputs to console in extendscript:
none,0,12
Arial   Bold,13,29
Arial   Italic,30,33
Arial   Bold
none,34,39
Arial   Italic,40,44
Arial   Bold,45,49
Arial   Bold Italic,50,63
Arial   Bold,64,73
Arial   Italic,74,80
none,81,87
This is some really important text with some very very <br> very important things in it.
Result: undefined
*/
```

Comment: First, you'll get more respect & attention to your question if you choose an actual name rather than "user1626601". Second, what is the <bi> tag? There's no such thing.

Comment: Voter-to-close: what's wrong with the question?

Comment: We're working with custom fonts, so we made up the <bi> tag for a font that is both italic and bold.  Is there a standard for this?  Maybe <b><i>text</i></b>?

Comment: Maybe try a different approach: use [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) to convert HTML to Adobe InCopy's ICML format. The resulting file can then be placed in InDesign like any other external dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I'm waiting for the explanation of the `<bi>` tag, but in the meantime here's some code that strips out the tags and collects the information you need. I'm also not 100% clear on the font stuff. Are the values in TAGSOBJ the ones needed to actually apply the formatting?

```
var
    content = 'This is some <b>really important <i>text</i></b> with <i>some <b>very very <br>very important</b> things</i> in it.',
    tagPattern = /<\/?(i|b)\b[^>]*>/ig,
    stack = [],
    tags = [],
    offset = 0,
    match,
    tag;

while (match = tagPattern.exec(content)) {
    if (match[0].substr(1, 1) !== '/') {
        stack.push(match.index - offset);
    } else {
        tags.push({
            tag: match[1],
            from: stack.splice(-1, 1)[0],
            to: match.index - offset
        });
    }
    offset += match[0].length;
}
content = content.replace(tagPattern, '');
// now use tags array and perform needed actions.
```

Here's [a fiddle demonstrating this](http://jsfiddle.net/Sf7JC/).

Last, for what it's worth, I don't think it is standard practice to use upper-case identifiers in javascript.

Comment: Yes, the values in TAGSOBJ will be used to apply the font/style to the text.